# Who's viewing website source code?

Tags: web-development

Is there a way (either client side or server side) to see who is viewing your website's source code that is generated in the their browser?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Comment: Curiosity. I want to see who is admiring my work.

Comment: That would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is not currently possible.

Comment: Thought so, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old uestion, but as John said, it's not possible, because you could (for example) write an app that fetches the page like a browser would, but just displays the results instead of parsing it. To a server, there's no difference between getting a page and viewing the source, as they all make GET calls in the end.

You might not be able to see who is doing it, but you could give someone an incentive to "check in". For example, putting a goo.gl link in the source as a comment, or writing the link to the console. That way if you get hits to that link, you know that someone might be clicking the link (if it's not a crawler).

To add on to that, you could make the link go to a form with a textbox, and tell people in the console or comment to type a specific word in with the promise of showing them something cool or giving them a discount on something.

Not a guarantee, but a fun way for people to let you know that they're looking at your work.